# Spring StoredProcedure Optional Parameters

Tags: java, spring, oracle11g, java-stored-procedures

I have a procedure in Oracle that has 12 total parameters and 3 optional. How can I account for these optional parameters if I'm using the [StoredProcedure](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html) object in Spring 3.1.0?

Here's what I have so far in my StoredProcedure class

```
public Map<String, Object> execute(Evaluation evaluation) {
    Map<String, Object> input_params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    input_params.put(COURSE_MAIN_PK1_INPUT_PARAM, evaluation.getCourseId());
    input_params.put(USERS_PK1_INPUT_PARAM, evaluation.getUsersPk1());
    input_params.put(ACCREDITATION_PK1_INPUT_PARAM, evaluation.getAccreditationPk1());
    input_params.put(TYPE_PK1_INPUT_PARAM, evaluation.getTypePk1());
    input_params.put(PRIVACY_TYPE_PK1_INPUT_PARAM, evaluation.getPrivacyTypePk1());
    input_params.put(FORM_TYPE_PK1_INPUT_PARAM, evaluation.getFormTypePk1());
    input_params.put(TITLE_INPUT_PARAM, evaluation.getTitle());
    input_params.put(DESCRIPTION_INPUT_PARAM, evaluation.getDescription());

    if(evaluation.getStartDate() != null) {
        input_params.put(START_DATE_INPUT_PARAM, new java.sql.Date(evaluation.getStartDate().getMillis()));         
    }

    if(evaluation.getEndDate() != null) {
        input_params.put(END_DATE_INPUT_PARAM, new java.sql.Date(evaluation.getEndDate().getMillis())); 
    }

    input_params.put(SAVE_TO_GRADECENTER_INPUT_PARAM, evaluation.getGradeCenterColumn());
    input_params.put(CREATE_ANNOUNCEMENT_INPUT_PARAM, evaluation.getAnnouncement());

    return super.execute(input_params);
}
```

The problem with this is that I'm supplying 12 parameters and if the start and end dates are null, now I'm supplying 10 and getting an exception.

The default values for the dates in the database is `null`.

Comment: Since `Map` can contain `null` values, did you try to just add startDate and endDate keys to the map always and see if the stored procedure runs fine in both cases where the dates are null and non-null?

Comment: Yes, When there is a date, it runs fine, but the problem is when the `evaluation.getStartDate().getMillis()` supplied to the `java.sql.Date` constructor returns a null, I get a `NullPointerException`. So what I'd like to do is not supply the parameter if it is null and let the procedure insert the default value instead (null).

Comment: I meant to say that if `evaluation.getStartDate() == null`, then try with `input_params.put(START_DATE_INPUT_PARAM, null)`. Similarly for `evaluation.getEndDate == null` as well.

Comment: That worked! I don't know how to accept your answer if it's in the comments??

Comment: i have added the explanation of why you should do this, to the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JDBC's [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) provides a facility to set null values to parameters using the `setNull` method. So, as long as you pass all the parameters to the stored procedure if they are null, Spring would be able to prepare the statement and execute it.

So, you needed to add the input parameters whose values are null, to the Map that is sent to the stored procedure call.

```
input_params.put(START_DATE_INPUT_PARAM, 
                 (null != evaluation.getStartDate() 
                  ? new java.sql.Date(evaluation.getStartDate().getMillis()) 
                  : null));
```

The same would apply to END_DATE_INPUT_PARAM as well.